# Android - States for different imageview resources as a listview items

Tags: android, listview

I've customized a listview item.
Each item list has an imageview.

The type of the imageview is defined by a category variable, that I save in a DB.

So lets's say there are three items in the listview with those three categories  - blue, red and black.

So the bindView of the CursorAdapter is as following -

```
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

String cat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constans.CATEGORY));

ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("black")) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_un);
            }

            if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_un);
            }

            if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_un);
            }

}
```

Now what I would like to do is when the listviewitem is being pressed - I want that the imageview will show the relevant "pressed" image -

what I mean is that now the imageview is showing the non pressed state image - 
but when the user pressing on the listview item I want that it will show the "pressed" image - and than the imageview will present the non pressed image again - just as you can do with a button.

Any ideas how can I do that? Mind that there's a different image at each listview raw - depends of course on the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use selector for this:

selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/not_pressed_image" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" android:state_pressed="true"></item>

</selector>
```

Rather than setting one drawable set the selector like:

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.selector);
```

Comment: Could you help with something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161966/how-to-set-the-background-of-a-custom-shaped-imagebutton-in-index-0-of-a-recycle/36162362#36162362